# ColdFusion large number comparison

Tags: coldfusion, precision, bigint

ColdFusion thinks `10090000000557765` = `10090000000557763`.

I get why but I need to know the best way for ColdFusion to know they are NOT the same. I read about the `Compare()` method but that also returns true. I've casted them as strings and also returns true.

I thought about writing a custom function to break the string into two parts, compare each individually and then return true/false but that seems dumb.

I've Tried the following:

```
Val(a) EQ Val(b)
ToString(a) EQ ToString(b)
a.compareTo(b)
```

**For clarification.** I'm using a DB I don't control that uses bigint. I learned early on that Javascript couldn't handle these so I converted all the bigint fields to varchar in my models. Now however, CF is having issue comparing the strings and I can't it seems convert them back to numbers.

Example I just did:

```
<cfif '10090000000557765' EQ '10090000000557763'>
True
<cfelse>
False
</cfif>
```

On http://cflive.net/ and it returned true. See my note. In the DB they are bigint. I had to cast them as VarChar when getting them out because Javascript can't handle bigint but it does strings just fine.

Comment: Show the code you use to compare them.

Comment: I thought about adding more random letters to the string to make it more different or make it a hash or something but those just seem like I still might run into the same issues. In my model's I've already casted all of these as strings as javascript was having issues with them as well. ColdFusion seemed to be handling them better when they were numbers I thought. Seems like CF likes bigint but Javascript doesn't. Now that they are strings, comparison in ColdFusion is broken and I can't convert them back to numbers.

Comment: I just tried doing `hash(a) EQ hash(b)` and that works but it just seems like CF should have something built in to handle this.

Comment: I occasionally see the term, `precisionEvaluate()` come up in questions like this.

Comment: Reading that I don't see how that helps. I'm comparing not doing arithmetic. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, `precisionEvaluate()` might be helpful. Ben Nadal wrote an interesting blog a few years ago where he explores the underlying Java BigInteger class. It might give you some ideas: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2020-experimenting-with-java-math-biginteger-in-coldfusion.htm

Comment: @Leeish - FWIW, all of the methods you mentioned worked fine under CF11, except val() for obvious reasons. ie 1) CF Compare() two strings 2) Compare two query columns (BigInt / SQL Server) 3) Compare two query columns (Varchar, SQL Server). So something must be different on your end. How the values are stored and retrieved is very relevant.  Can you please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Also, your CF version and DBMS.

Comment: Also, so as not to overlook the obvious ... java methods like [Long.compareTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compareTo%28java.lang.Long%29) return -1, 0, or 1. Double check that you are using the correct expression to test for equality.  ie The values are only considered equal if the result is `0`.

Comment: Speaking of obvious, I never use compare functions.  I use comparison  operators  such as == so that it's more obvious what I'm attempting to achieve.

Comment: @Leigh I think I did overlook the obvious. The `compareTo` Java method did return a `2` in those two strings. I overlooked that in my frustration. However none of the other methods have worked.

Comment: @Leeish - Okay, good. That is what I got as well.  As far as the other methods, a lot depends on the specifics I mentioned (data types, exactly how they are retrieved and compared, etectera). I will post an example with my test code, in case it helps.

Comment: I understand the datatype issue somewhat and why long numbers fail in comparison. CF handled the bigint values just fine before I had to change them to strings because of Javascript. I recently became aware of the strings not comparing correctly. Something that is hard to catch unless you are looking for it.

Comment: *because of Javascript* Without knowing the specifics, I would ask why not? :) Storing numbers as strings just invites data integrity issues. However, that is probably a separate question altogether ...

Comment: @DanBracuk - If all things were equal (no pun intended) that would be my preference too. However, they are are not interchangeable. So the decision involves more than just personal preference.

Comment: Javascript cannot handle bigint. The accuracy of floating point numbers is the issue.  As far as I can tell it simply cannot be done. I didn't want to use varchar values everywhere but I had to cast them as such.  http://www.2ality.com/2012/07/large-integers.html  I could have passed both everywhere but that seems like a crazy thing to do as well.

Comment: Yes, I am not wild about passing both values either.  If maintaining integrity is important, I usually try and find a compromise, such as implementing a wrapper function ie setter/getter in the model or possibly using a *sql view*, which isolates the changes so they are not strewn throughout the code. Granted every app is different, so the best approach really depends.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The good news is the comparisons of the data typically happen in the model in the SQL itself. This is a unique situation where I am pre-selecting a HTML select drop down in the output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Short Answer:**  So as not to overlook the obvious, java methods like [Long.compareTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compareTo%28java.lang.Long%29) return `-1`, `0`, or `1`. Make sure you are using the correct expression to test for equality. The result will be `0` when the values are equal. (Zero (0) evaluates to `false` in CF).

**Longer answer:**
How the values are stored, retrieved and specifically *evaluated* is very relevant here. All of the methods you mentioned worked fine for me under CF11 (with the exception of `val`, for obvious reasons). Which suggests something is different in your code or environment.

For example, using CF11 and SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    bigIntValue1 BIGINT
    , bigIntValue2 BIGINT
    , varcharValue1 VARCHAR(50)
    , varcharValue2 VARCHAR(50)
)
```

The following test code:

```
writeOutput("<br>qry.bigIntValue1: "&  val(qry.bigIntValue1) );
writeOutput("<br>qry.bigIntValue2: "&  val(qry.bigIntValue2) );
writeOutput("<br>BigInt Val(): "& ( val(qry.bigIntValue1) eq val(qry.bigIntValue2)) );
writeOutput("<br>Varchar Val(): "& ( val(qry.varcharValue1) eq val(qry.varcharValue2)) );
writeOutput("<br>Long.compareTo: "& qry.bigIntValue1[1].compareTo(qry.bigIntValue2[1]));
writeOutput("<br>Varchar.compareTo: "& qry.varcharValue1[1].compareTo(qry.varcharValue2[1]));
writeOutput("<br>Compare(Long, Long) "& compare(qry.bigIntValue1, qry.bigIntValue2));
writeOutput("<br>Compare(Varchar, Varchar) "& compare(qry.varcharValue1, qry.varcharValue2));
```

Produces these results:

```
val(qry.bigIntValue1):     1.00900000006E+016
val(qry.bigIntValue21):    1.00900000006E+016
BigInt Val():              YES
Varchar Val():             YES

Long.compareTo:            1
Varchar.compareTo:         2
Compare(Long, Long):       1
Compare(Varchar, Varchar): 1
```

As expected, the `val()` comparison returns the wrong answer, because the function implicitly converts the large numbers to an *approximate* type. Once converted, these approximate values are considered equal.

All of the other comparisons indicate the values are NOT equal. While the examples use different functions, they all have one thing in common: they all return `0` when the values are considered equal. Anything else indicates the values are *different*. Since zero (0) is treated as `false` in CF, be sure you are using the correct expression to test for equality and differences.

- [Long.compareTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compareTo%28java.lang.Long%29) - (Data type used to represent BigInt in CF) *the value 0 if this Long is equal to the argument Long; a value less than 0 if this Long is numerically less than the argument Long; and a value greater than 0 if this Long is numerically greater than the argument Long (signed comparison)."*
- [String.compareTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) - *the value 0 if the argument string is equal to this string; a value less than 0 if this string is lexicographically less than the string argument; and a value greater than 0 if this string is lexicographically greater than the string argument.*
- [Compare(string1, string2)](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-c-d/Compare.html) - *"...Performs a case sensitive comparison of two strings.?* Returns -1 (less than), 0 (equal) or 1 (greater than)

Comment: I misunderstood how the functions worked. Thanks for your complete answer.

Answer (score 3):

I have another simple solution for this. I think it may help you.

```
<cfset x = 10090000000557765/>
<cfset y = 10090000000557763/>
<cfset isZero = PrecisionEvaluate( x-y )/>
<cfif isZero EQ 0>
   x and y are equal
<cfelse>
   x and y are not equal
</cfif>
```

As values exceeds its data type (like int, longInt etc.) limit then it become problematic to perform arithmetical operations. So I have used [PrecisionEvaluate()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/precisionevaluate.html).

Comment: Smart idea. Thanks for the input.

Comment: code has errors, also what do you mean by 'y and y are equal'?

Comment: line 1 - set variable 'Value1', line 2 - set again variable 'Value1' , line 3 use variables 'x' and 'y' never defined